# Spring Security Authenticating an Administrator with sql query

Tags: java, sql, spring-security

I have been trying to implement the administrator service spring security provides but I am finding it difficult, all my standard users can use the webapp but I cant seem to work out the sql required to authenticate that a user has a "ADMIN" role to allow them to view certain pages.

Any help advice would be greatly appreciated as I am new to this.
(Note: I am getting no errors in my console only the 403 username/password denied page)

My WebSecurityConfig file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
       UserLoginRepository userLoginRepository;


    //http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/home", "/registeruser").permitAll().antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")

     @Autowired
     DataSource dataSource;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/home", "/registeruser").permitAll().antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().logout()
                    .permitAll();
            http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
            http.csrf().disable();
            //disable csrf to allow communication (we also dont need for this fyp as its not live)
        }



    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        //authorities at the moment is the manager i.e. 'Manager' from user_login

//       String userByMailQuery = "SELECT user_type FROM user_login WHERE user_type = ?;";

           auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
          .usersByUsernameQuery("select user_name,password,user_status from user_login where user_name=?")
       .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select user_login_id, roles_id, role from user_login_roles, role where user_login_id=?");          




}

    }
```

The .authoritiesByUsernameQuery is the query im struggling with. The logic would be to check that a user has the role with the value of "ADMIN".

My UserLogin class:

```
@Entity
public class UserLogin {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private Long phone;
private String userName;
private String address;
private String password;
private boolean userStatus;
private String userType;
private String position;


@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public Set<Role> roles;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
 public Set<PlayerSeasonStat> playerStats;

public UserLogin()
{

}

public UserLogin(Long id, String firstName, String lastName, Long phone,
        String userName, String address, String password,
        boolean userStatus, String userType, String position,
        Set<Role> roles, Set<PlayerSeasonStat> playerStats) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.address = address;
    this.password = password;
    this.userStatus = userStatus;
    this.userType = userType;
    this.position = position;
    this.roles = roles;
    this.playerStats = playerStats;
}




public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    if (roles==null)
        roles = new HashSet<>();


    return roles;
}

public void setRole(Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}

public void addRole(Role role){

    getRoles().add(role);
}
```

My role class:

```
@Entity
public class Role {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String role;


    public Role()
    {

    }


    public Role(Long id, String role) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.role = role;
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }


    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }



}
```

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
@dur I know this sql query is not correct

Comment: So basically your question is not about Spring Security, it is just: how to write a SQL query? If you work with databases you should have at least this basic knowledge. However, show the tables with colums. You need to use an inner join between `user_login`, `user_login_role` and `role` table.

Comment: @dur Evidently I have some sort of knowledge of SQL queries as I can enable a generic log in for users using an SQL query. 
My question which may not be worded the best, is asking how do I replicate this for an Administrator, as Spring Security seems to require a particular way of implementing this via a SQL query.
However after all of these unnecessaries you have pointed me in the right direction! Thank you

Comment: The SQL query for a non admin user is much more straight forward then for an admin user, for example, it would make much more sense for me to go:
`.authoritiesByUsernameQuery("user_type from user_login where user_type='Manager'"); `
But that doesn't work as I need a role entity with String variable called role, your suggestion of using an inner join makes more sense!

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm missing something. You have a user table (for  all users including admins) and you have a role table. So the query is always the same. You load the user and get the role names. For admin users the role name is 'admin', for other users the role name is something different like `user`. However, you need an inner joing anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164769/discussion-between-gavin-james-beere-and-dur).

Answer (score 1):

You can make a use of HandlerInterceptor where you can check login role is admin or not. with the method prehandle() of HandlerInterceptor interface you can handle the request and check the role and if login role does not match you can dispatch the request to 403 page

After login add Role Object to session, `request.getSession().setAttribute("LOGGEDIN_USER_ROLE",roleObject)`  and you can make use of HandlerInterceptorAdapter

```
public class SecurityInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {


  @Override
  public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Interceptor: Pre-handle");

    // Avoid a redirect loop for some urls
    if(request.getRequestURI().equals("/admin-page")){
          Role  role = (Role) request.getSession().getAttribute("LOGGEDIN_USER_ROLE");
          if(!role.getRole().equalsIgnoreCase("ADMIN")){
             response.sendRedirect("/403/");
            return false;
       }   
      }

    return true;
}

 @Override
 public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

  }

 }
```

Comment: I have tried to implement this into my project but it didn't seem to work , I will research more into this topic though, thank you!